# Dummy output issue in Ubuntu 22.04, now showing HDMI / Display Port as output device. No Sound, no mic

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi, microphone

after I switched off on my system last night with perfectly working audio, when I started it u p, I got the dummy output issue. After trying out the variety of solutions available online, nothing seems to work.

The earlier 'dummy output' is now showing 'HDMI / Display Port', but still no Sound, no mic.

```
$ sudo lspci -v

0000:00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9a04 (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 881d
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>

0000:00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 9a78 (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 881d
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 159
    Memory at 6002000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at 4000000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 5000 [size=64]
    Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [40] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
    Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [ac] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable+ 64bit-
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [100] Process Address Space ID (PASID)
    Capabilities: [200] Address Translation Service (ATS)
    Capabilities: [300] Page Request Interface (PRI)
    Capabilities: [320] Single Root I/O Virtualization (SR-IOV)
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915

0000:00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation TigerLake-LP Dynamic Tuning Processor Participant (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company TigerLake-LP Dynamic Tuning Processor Participant
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at 6003200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
    Kernel driver in use: proc_thermal
    Kernel modules: processor_thermal_device_pci_legacy

0000:00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation GNA Scoring Accelerator module (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company GNA Scoring Accelerator module
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 255
    Memory at 600322f000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [a0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Capabilities: [dc] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [f0] PCI Advanced Features

0000:00:0e.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation Volume Management Device NVMe RAID Controller
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Volume Management Device NVMe RAID Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Memory at 6000000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32M]
    Memory at 50000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32M]
    Memory at 6003100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: [80] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=19 Masked-
    Capabilities: [90] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [e0] Power Management version 3
    Kernel driver in use: vmd
    Kernel modules: vmd

0000:00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP USB 3.2 Gen 2x1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 20) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Tiger Lake-LP USB 3.2 Gen 2x1 xHCI Host Controller
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 144
    Memory at 52200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/8 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [90] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Capabilities: [b0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=00 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci

0000:00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Shared SRAM (rev 20)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Tiger Lake-LP Shared SRAM
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Memory at 6003224000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at 600322e000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3

0000:00:15.0 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 20)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Tiger Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 27
    Memory at 4017000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [virtual] [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [90] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

0000:00:15.1 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 20)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Tiger Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 40
    Memory at 4017001000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [virtual] [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [90] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

0000:00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Management Engine Interface (rev 20)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Tiger Lake-LP Management Engine Interface
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 157
    Memory at 600322b000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [8c] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [a4] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me

0000:00:17.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 09ab
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 881d
    Flags: fast devsel

0000:00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev 20) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 122
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00004000-00004fff [size=4K]
    Memory behind bridge: 52100000-521fffff [size=1M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled]
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Tiger Lake-LP PCI Express Root Port
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [220] Access Control Services
    Capabilities: [200] L1 PM Substates
    Capabilities: [a30] Secondary PCI Express
    Capabilities: [a00] Downstream Port Containment
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

0000:00:1d.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a0b1 (rev 20) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 123
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00003000-00003fff [size=4K]
    Memory behind bridge: 52000000-520fffff [size=1M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled]
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 881d
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [220] Access Control Services
    Capabilities: [200] L1 PM Substates
    Capabilities: [a30] Secondary PCI Express
    Capabilities: [a00] Downstream Port Containment
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

0000:00:1e.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Serial IO UART Controller #0 (rev 20)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Tiger Lake-LP Serial IO UART Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at 4017002000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [virtual] [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [90] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

0000:00:1e.3 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Serial IO SPI Controller #1 (rev 20)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Tiger Lake-LP Serial IO SPI Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 37
    Memory at 4017003000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [virtual] [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [90] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

0000:00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP LPC Controller (rev 20)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Tiger Lake-LP LPC Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0

0000:00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller (rev 20)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 16
    Memory at 6003220000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at 6003000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [80] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl

0000:00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP SMBus Controller (rev 20)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Tiger Lake-LP SMBus Controller
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 16
    Memory at 6003228000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at efa0 [size=32]
    Kernel driver in use: i801_smbus
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801

0000:00:1f.5 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP SPI Controller (rev 20)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Tiger Lake-LP SPI Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Memory at 4f800000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Kernel driver in use: intel-spi
    Kernel modules: spi_intel_pci

0000:01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
    DeviceName: Hanksville Gbe Lan Connection
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    I/O ports at 4000 [size=256]
    Memory at 52104000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at 52100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 01
    Capabilities: [b0] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=4 Masked-
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number 01-00-00-00-68-4c-e0-00
    Capabilities: [170] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [178] L1 PM Substates
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169

0000:02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
    DeviceName: WLAN
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8822CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 158
    I/O ports at 3000 [size=256]
    Memory at 52000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [148] Device Serial Number 00-e0-4c-ff-fe-c8-22-01
    Capabilities: [158] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [160] L1 PM Substates
    Kernel driver in use: rtw_8822ce
    Kernel modules: rtw88_8822ce

10000:e0:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device a0d3 (rev 20) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 145
    Memory at 50100000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Memory at 50102800 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at <unassigned> [disabled]
    I/O ports at <unassigned> [disabled]
    I/O ports at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Memory at 50102000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [a8] SATA HBA v1.0
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci

10000:e0:1c.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 09ab
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 881d
    Flags: fast devsel

10000:e0:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a0bc (rev 20) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 143
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=e1, subordinate=e1, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: [disabled]
    Memory behind bridge: 50000000-500fffff [size=1M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled]
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Device 0000:0000
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [220] Access Control Services
    Capabilities: [200] L1 PM Substates
    Capabilities: [a30] Secondary PCI Express
    Capabilities: [a00] Downstream Port Containment
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

10000:e1:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Sandisk Corp WD Black SN750 / PC SN730 NVMe SSD (prog-if 02 [NVM Express])
    Subsystem: Sandisk Corp WD Black SN750 / PC SN730 NVMe SSD
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, NUMA node 0
    Memory at 50000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at 50004000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable- Count=1/32 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [b0] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=65 Masked-
    Capabilities: [c0] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [150] Device Serial Number 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
    Capabilities: [1b8] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [300] Secondary PCI Express
    Capabilities: [900] L1 PM Substates
    Kernel driver in use: nvme
    Kernel modules: nvme
```

Further,

```
$ inxi -A

Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.19.0-35-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
  Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes
  
  
$ aplay -l

**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: Generic Analog [Generic Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: Generic Digital [Generic Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Please help. Noob at linux, stuck at this for hours. Let me know for any further details required.

Comment: So, you are saying, you did nothing but rebooted the system, and then HDMI and DP outputs disappeared completely? So you didn't change some config files or settings before the reboot, simply used the system as normal and then rebooted? That sounds like a hardware issue then, why would otherwise a plain reboot result in such a problem. Thus what I'd test in this case is try booting from a Live USB system and check if it has sound. If it doesn't, then it's definitely something hardware related.

Comment: Yes. Okay, I'll try the USB approach, and update further.

Comment: Found some sort of a HW-probe online, the results are on https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=bdfaf09cd0

Comment: Btw, are you sure you didn't update the kernel? There's some other thread where the `5.19.0.35` kernel version caused boot problems. Since you has the same version, I'm just wondering if that can be related. You should still have older kernel versions in the boot menu, so you can try booting them to test that hypothesis.

Comment: Okay, sorry for the late response. I'll try that. That won't make me lose my work though, would it?

Comment: No, you won't lose anything. Just make Grub menu appear on boot *(AFAIR if it doesn't by default, you need to hold `Esc` or `Shift`)*, and in "additional options" menu *(or similarly named, there's just a few of them)* choose the entry with an older kernel.

Comment: Tried this. Initially no sound, but when restarted, stopped detecting the speakers altogether.

Edit - Restarting the second time, showing speakers atleast, but still no sound. Still not detecting the mic though.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue by wiping the laptop clean and reinstalling Ubuntu. Works fine now.